# Boost::Thread / C++11 std::thread, want to wake worker thread on condition

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, c++11

I am using a Boost::thread as a worker-thread.  I want to put the worker thread to sleep when there is no work to be done and wake it up as soon as there is work to be done.  I have two variables that hold integers.  When the integers are equal, there is no work to be done.  When the integers are different, there is work to be done.  My current code looks like this:

```
int a;
int b;

void worker_thread()
{
    while(true) {
        if(a != b) {
            //...do something
        }
                    //if a == b, then just waste CPU cycles
    }
}

//other code running in the main thread that changes the values of a and b
```

I tried using a condition variable and having the worker thread go to sleep when a == b.  The problem is that there is a race condition.  Here is an example situation:

1. Worker thread evaluates if(a == b), finds that it is true.
2. Main thread changes a and/or b such that they are no longer equal.  Calls notify_one() on the worker thread.
3. Worker thread ignores notify_one() since it is still awake.
4. Worker thread goes to sleep.
   Deadlock

What would be better is if I could avoid the condition variables since I don't actually need to lock anything.  But just have the worker thread go to sleep whenever a == b and wake up whenever a != b.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: "Since I don't actually need to lock anything"... I believe this is called "optimistic concurrency".

Answer (score 4):

It seems you are not properly synchronizing your accesses: When you read `a` and `b` in the work thread, you'll need to acquire a lock, at least, while accessing the value shared with the producer: since there is a lock held by the work thread, neither `a` nor `b` can be changed by the main thread. If they are not equal, the work thread can release the lock and churn away processing the values. If they are equal, the work thread instead `wait()`s on the condition variable *while* the lock is held! The main functionality of the condition variable is to atomically release the lock and go to sleep.

When the main thread updates `a` and/or `b` it acquires the lock, does the changes, releases the lock and notifies the worker thread. The work thread clearly didn't held the lock but acquires it either when the next check is due or as a result of the notification, checks the state of the values and either `wait()`s or processes the values.

When done correctly, there is no potential for a race condition!

I missed your key confusion: "Since I don't actually need to lock anything"! Well, when you have two threads which concurrently may access the same value and, at least, one of them is modifying the value, you have a data race if there is no synchronization. Any program which has a data race has undefined behavior. Put differently: even if you want to only sent a `bool` value from one thread to another thread, you do need synchronization. The synchronization doesn't have to take the form of locks (the values can be synchronized using atomic variables, for example) but doing non-trivial communication, e.g., involving two `int`s rather than just one with atomics is generally quite hard! You almost certainly *want* to use a lock. You may not have discovered this deep desire, yet, however.

Comment: I structured my program in such a way that (as far as I can tell) there is no contention.  Part of what I said above was inaccurate...I was just trying to simplify the problem statement.  What happens is that the worker thread modifies only one variable.  The main thread modifies only the other variable.  But both threads read both variables.  If a stale value is read, no problem, the main thread either goes through a while loop another time and waits to receive the updated value or the worker thread will only do part of the work, the rest will get finished on the next iteration....cont

Comment: (continued from above comment) Although I am assuming that at any time, the integers (actually pointers) that I am reading will either be the old value or the new value.  For example, say one thread tries to update an integer at the exact same time that the other thread is trying to read it.  It's ok if the thread trying to read it gets the old value or the new value, but the program will break if it gets something else.  From what I have read, that won't happen on my architecture (X86) for an integer or pointer datatype.

Comment: @486DX2-66: Let me but it into simple terms: if one thread writes a value and another thread reads a value and one or both threads are missing synchronization, you have undefined behavior! That is, without synchronization the program is wrong. The relevant quote from the standard is 1.10 [intro.multithread] paragraph 21: "The execution of a program contains a data race if it contains two conflicting actions in different threads, at least one of which is not atomic, and neither happens before the other. Any such data race results in undefined behavior. ..."

Comment: @486DX2-66: The referred to "happens before" relation depends on some level of synchronization, also described in 1.10 [intro.multithread]. The section is somewhat non-trivial but the definition certainly doesn't depends on times but rather on synchronization primitives.

Answer (score 0):

Things to think about:

1. Is there a reason for your threads to stay asleep at all?
2. Why not launch a new thread and let it die a nice natural death when it has finished its work?
3. If there is only one code path active at any point in time (all other threads are asleep), then your design does not allow for concurrency.

Finally, if you're using variables that are shared between threads, you should be using [atomics](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic). This will make sure that access to your values are synchonized.

Comment: Atomics are generally for experts only, for many programs locks are simpler and easier to get right. If you need to wait for a condition to be true, spinning on atomics is a waste of cycles.

Comment: I'm trying to build a buffered logstream with one producer and one consumer.  It must be FIFO and I want to avoid the overhead of launching a new thread for each incoming message.  Furthermore, if I use a different thread to process each message, I cannot control the message ordering -- an earlier message might finish after a message that arrived later.  My aim is not increasing throughput (no way to do that without hardware changes), but instead reduce latency.  Basically, when a message arrives from the application, main thread copies it into buffer.  Worker thread then prints it to file.